# Can't find the file I moved to my desktop after I used the "mv" command in Linux in Ubuntu 18.04 running on VMware

Tags: vmware-workstation, syslinux

I'm very new to this, please forgive me, So I did " mv file1.desktop ~/desktop" and then I did "mv name-filename.png ~/desktop" for the png file associated with my desktop file after and now I can't find either. Does anyone know why or where it went? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you're trying to accomplish? What do you mean by "...png associated with my desktop file"?

Comment: `~/desktop`  is a file name not a directory so I assume it will be named desktop and is in your home. Desktop/ would be the directory. Mind the D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably intended to move both files to the `~/Desktop` directory. Unfortunately, Linux is case-sensitive by default, and there is likely no `~/desktop` directory. In that case,

```
mv file1.desktop ~/desktop
```

would have *renamed* `file1.desktop` to `~/desktop` (a plain file, inside your home directory `~`) and then

```
mv name-filename.png ~/desktop
```

would have renamed `name-filename.png` *to the same name*, `~/desktop`, overwriting the old `file1.desktop`.

For reasons like this, I'd recommend trying to get into the habit of adding a trailing `/` when the target is a directory; that way, you will get a helpful message like

```
/home/steeldriver/desktop/: Not a directory
```

and the renaming will fail. You could also consider aliasing `mv` to `mv -i` (to make it prompt you for confirmation) or even `mv -n` (which will prevent accidental "clobbering" of an existing file). See `man mv` for these and other options.

Comment: Also, use `mv -i` so it'll warn you before overwriting files (or `mv -n` to just *not* overwrite)! The default behavior makes it way to easy to accidentally destroy files. Same goes for `cp -i` by the way.

Comment: @GordonDavisson good point - added. I also mentioned `-n` (`--no-clobber`)

Answer (score 1):

```
mv file1.desktop ~/desktop
```

you will have a file named desktop in your home/

You should have typed

```
mv file1.desktop ~/Desktop/
```

Mind the capital D. And it is always a good idea to end a move to an existing directory with a /. It will show an error when you make a mistake in typing the destination. Do a ...

```
mv ~/desktop ~/Desktop/file1.desktop
```

to fix your problem.

Comment: Thank you. So I would have to reinstall the file I overwrote then?